# creating multiple edit parts in one drag from palette in GEF eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gef

I am currently using GEF framework for one of my requirement.
wish to create multiple figures with independent figures when dragging an item from the palette. 
i am not sure the best approach to take for this. an edit part can only
create a single figure with child's inside. But i need independent figures.

Please let me know is there any way in GEF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your implementation of EditPartFactory. When you drag an object from your Palette or viewer which contains the templates, create your model objects in class which implements CreationFactory.